# express-validator not wotking

Tags: node.js, express

i have create register form and i want to validate form. I am using  express-validator middleware but i am able to validate. But if input type if valid value show still validation error message.
my module code is:
please help.

```
<pre>
    const { body,sanitizeBody } = require('express-validator');
    exports.registerform=[
    
    body('fristName','Frist Name must be at least 2 chars long.').isLength({ min: 2 }),
        body('lastName','Last name must be at least 2 chars long.').isLength({ min: 2 }),
        body('email','must be a valid email.').isEmail(),
        body('gender','please select gender.').isLength({ min: 2 }),
        body('dob','Please provide date of birth.').isLength({ min: 2 }),
        body('skills','Please any one skill.').isLength({ min: 2 }),
        body('password','Password required').trim().notEmpty()
        .isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('password must be minimum 5 length')
        .matches(/(?=.*?[A-Z])/).withMessage('At least one Uppercase')
        .matches(/(?=.*?[a-z])/).withMessage('At least one Lowercase')
        .matches(/(?=.*?[0-9])/).withMessage('At least one Number')
        .matches(/(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])/).withMessage('At least one special character')
        .not().matches(/^$|\s+/).withMessage('White space not allowed'),
        body('confirm_password').custom((value, { req }) => {
          if (value !== req.body.password) {
                throw new Error('Password Confirmation does not match password');
           }
          })
    ]
    </pre>
```

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkZ4L.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough on where you are encountering the issue

Comment: please check attachment images

Answer (score 0):

this is problem resolved. I validate validation middleware after multer middleware.
thank you.